# PHP data handling difficulties

Tags: php, http-post, storage, string-comparison

I have the following problem.

I have a jQuery accordion which is used to save milestones and inside each milestone I have a button to add an event to the milestone. That works fine. The way I assign names to each input is the following.

```
<input type="text" name="milestone_0_name">
<input type="text" name="milestone_0_start_date">
<input type="text" name="milestone_0_end_date">
<input type="text" name="milestone_0_description">
<input type="text" name="milestone_1_name">
<input type="text" name="milestone_1_start_date">
<input type="text" name="milestone_1_end_date">
<input type="text" name="milestone_1_description">
<input type="text" name="milestone_2_name">
<input type="text" name="milestone_2_start_date">
<input type="text" name="milestone_2_end_date">
<input type="text" name="milestone_2_description">
and so on...
```

So afterwards when I add events to milestone_0 for example the generated markup is as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="milestone_0_events_event_0_event_name">
<input type="text" name="milestone_0_events_event_0_event_start_date">
<input type="text" name="milestone_0_events_event_1_event_name">
<input type="text" name="milestone_0_events_event_1_event_start_date">
```

I am not an expert in `$_POST` data handling so I use this way to know what events belong to a certain milestone. The problem is that the function I'm using to identify how many variables form a milestone (the milestone's info and each event info) has a problem I can't seem to find.

The function is:

```
// Assign all $_POST data to $milestones
$milestones = $_POST;
print_r($milestones);


$milestoneNames = array();
$milestoneSize = array();

$default = "milestone_";
$indexOfMilestone=0;
$ind=0;
$text=$default.$indexOfMilestone;
$indexOfIteration=0;
$actualSize=0;
$change=false;

foreach($milestones as $ms)
{
    $currKey = KeyName($milestones,$indexOfIteration);
    echo $text.'.'.$currKey.'<br />';
    $pos = strripos($currKey, $text);
    if ($pos === false) 
    {
        $milestoneSize[$indexOfMilestone] = $indexOfIteration;
        $indexOfMilestone++;
        $text=$default.$indexOfMilestone;
    }
$indexOfIteration++;
}

print_r($milestoneSize);
```

With test data, the output is:

```
    [milestone_0_name] => Milestone 1
    [milestone_0_start_date] => 12-4-25
    [milestone_0_end_date] => 12-4-26
    [milestone_0_description] => abcdefg
    [milestone_0_events_event_0_event_name] => asdg
    [milestone_0_events_event_0_event_start_date] => ff
    [milestone_0_events_event_1_event_name] => fghjk
    [milestone_0_events_event_1_event_start_date] => ff
    [milestone_0_events_event_2_event_name] => zxcv
    [milestone_0_events_event_2_event_start_date] => ff
    [milestone_0_events_event_3_event_name] => bnm,
    [milestone_0_events_event_3_event_start_date] => zz
    [milestone_0_events_event_4_event_name] => qwerty
    [milestone_0_events_event_4_event_start_date] => zz
    [milestone_0_events_event_5_event_name] => uiop
    [milestone_0_events_event_5_event_start_date] => zz
    [milestone_1_name] => Milestone 2
    [milestone_1_start_date] => 12-4-26
    [milestone_1_end_date] => 12-4-27
    [milestone_1_description] => sadg ads asdgasdg adsga sgdsa gsad adsg asdg
    [milestone_1_events_event_0_event_name] => 1234
    [milestone_1_events_event_0_event_start_date] => ff
    [milestone_1_events_event_1_event_name] => 4321
    [milestone_1_events_event_1_event_start_date] => ff
    [milestone_1_events_event_2_event_name] => 6542
    [milestone_1_events_event_2_event_start_date] => ff
)

milestone_0.milestone_0_name
milestone_0.milestone_0_start_date
milestone_0.milestone_0_end_date
milestone_0.milestone_0_description
milestone_0.milestone_0_events_event_0_event_name
milestone_0.milestone_0_events_event_0_event_start_date
milestone_0.milestone_0_events_event_1_event_name
milestone_0.milestone_0_events_event_1_event_start_date
milestone_0.milestone_0_events_event_2_event_name
milestone_0.milestone_0_events_event_2_event_start_date
milestone_0.milestone_0_events_event_3_event_name
milestone_0.milestone_0_events_event_3_event_start_date
milestone_0.milestone_0_events_event_4_event_name
milestone_0.milestone_0_events_event_4_event_start_date
milestone_0.milestone_0_events_event_5_event_name
milestone_0.milestone_0_events_event_5_event_start_date
**milestone_0.milestone_1_name**
milestone_1.milestone_1_start_date
milestone_1.milestone_1_end_date
milestone_1.milestone_1_description
milestone_1.milestone_1_events_event_0_event_name
milestone_1.milestone_1_events_event_0_event_start_date
milestone_1.milestone_1_events_event_1_event_name
milestone_1.milestone_1_events_event_1_event_start_date
milestone_1.milestone_1_events_event_2_event_name
milestone_1.milestone_1_events_event_2_event_start_date

Array ( [0] => 16 )
```

The issue occurs in the line marked in bold or ** ** (not sure if preview works right), the milestone_0 should be milestone_1. And that problem ruins the whole counting process :).

Anyway, if that's not a good way to store the data from `$_POST` I'm open to suggestions to improve my data storage.

Comment: I would restructure the POST data into arrays: `Milestone[1][Name]`, `Milestone[1][Events][5][Name]`...

Comment: Can you show me an example syntax of how to handle inputs like mine to generate the arrays you mentioned? It would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you requested, here's how I would structure the form:

```
<ul class="milestones">

 <li>
  <label>
   Name
   <input type="text" name="milestones[0][name]">
  </label>
  <label>
   Start date
   <input type="text" name="milestones[0][start_date]">
  </label>
  <label>
   End date
   <input type="text" name="milestones[0][end_date]">
  </label>
  <label>
   Description
   <input type="text" name="milestones[0][description]">
  </label>
 <ul class="events">
  <li>
   <label>
    Name
    <input type="text" name="milestones[0][events][0][name]">
   </label>
   <label>
    Start date
    <input type="text" name="milestones[0][events][0][start_date]">
   </label> 
  </li>
  <li>
   <label>
    Name
    <input type="text" name="milestones[0][events][1][name]">
   </label>
   <label>
    Start date
    <input type="text" name="milestones[0][events][1][start_date]">
   </label> 
  </li>
 </ul>
</li>

 <li>
  <label>
   Name
   <input type="text" name="milestones[1][name]">
  </label>
  <label>
   Start date
   <input type="text" name="milestones[1][start_date]">
  </label>
  <label>
   End date
   <input type="text" name="milestones[1][end_date]">
  </label>
  <label>
   Description
   <input type="text" name="milestones[1][description]">
  </label>
 </li>

</ul>
```

This will produce POST data like:

```
milestones => array(
 0 => array(
  name => "name",
  start_date => "2012-04-25",
  end_date => "2012-04-28",
  description => "desc",
  events => array(
   0 => array(
    name => "name0",
    start_date => "date0",
   ),
   1 => array(
    name => "name1",
    start_date => "date1",
   ),
  ),
 ),
 1 => array(
  name => "name",
  start_date => "2012-05-01",
  end_date => "2012-05-14",
  description => "desc",
 ),
)
```

Comment: Excellent :) I owe you a six pack of beers :)